# ASP.NET MVC4 menu link activate when controller and action matches

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, menu

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 application and my left navigation menu is under a CommonController so from my _Layout.cshtml I render it like:

```
<div class="leftmenu">        
    @Html.Action("LeftMenu", "Common")
</div><!--leftmenu-->
```

Now, in my partial view **LeftMenu** I have all the HTML code for displaying the menu items and what I want to do is to highlight the right menu item based on the current page controller and action.

**LeftMenu.cshtml**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
<li class="nav-header">Navigation Menu</li>
<li>@Html.MenuLink("Test Link", "Index", "Home", "active",true)</li>
......
```

Right now Im using the following helper code:

```
public static HtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string activeClass, bool checkAction)
        {
            string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

            if (string.Compare(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 && ((!checkAction) || string.Compare(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
            {
                return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, null, new { @class = activeClass });
            }

            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);

        }
```

The issue that Im having is that the currentController is "Common" because its where LeftMenu partial view is located.

I need to get the Main Page current controller and current action in order to make it work.

Any clue or advise on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving your "leftMenu.cshtml" to the Shared views folder beside your _Layout.cshtml and using it in your menu like this:

```
<div class="leftmenu">        
   @Html.Partial("LeftMenu")
</div>
<!--leftmenu-->
```

this way you will get the proper action name in your custom Helper.